Stripes in map are missing after gdalwarp and gdalbuildvrt
I have a problem with some GeoTIFF:s that are in EPSG:3006 and I need them in EPSG:3857. The problem is that after gdalwarp, and gdalbuildvrt I get transparent stripes in the vrt map
This is one of the maps reprojected to EPSG:3857, I did not make it transparent so it will show better how the image looks.

If I now warp two maps (with transparency) into EPSG:3857 and add them to QGIS it all looks good.
Command:
gdalwarp -dstalpha -dstnodata "255 255 255" -s_srs EPSG:3006 -t_srs EPSG:3857 J2aa_42_Mala_2.tif warped/J2aa_42_Mala_2_transparent.tif


But if I now create a vrt of these two maps stripes of the maps suddently disapears
Buildvrt: gdalbuildvrt test9.vrt warped/J*transparent.tif
The map after gdalbuildvrt when added to QGIS:

As seen there are now transparent stripes in the vrt map
Is there anything I can do in either gdalwarp or gdalbuildvrt to prevent this from happening? Or any other way to do this so I get a vrt in EPSG:3857 with the maps?
**** SOME MORE INFORMATION****
So, I have succeded on half of the images, the ones with the white border, I just removed the -dstalpha. But half of the images is different is some way. They have a blue border around the image and these ones still give me problem
This is the gdalwarp I run:
gdalwarp -dstnodata "255 255 255" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -co "TILED=YES" -s_srs EPSG:3006 -t_srs EPSG:3857 infile.tif outfile.tif

And then gdalbuildvrt:
gdalbuildvrt test.vrt *.tif

If I add the GeoTiffs by them self into QGIS they look fine. But the vrt looks like below.

This is the information from gdalinfo on one of the images with a blue border.
    Size is 12414, 9966
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["SWEREF99 TM",
    BASEGEOGCRS["SWEREF99",
        DATUM["SWEREF99",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4619]],
    CONVERSION["Transverse Mercator",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",3006]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (655527.025795543799177,7215009.693909364752471)
Pixel Size = (3.000000000000000,-3.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  655527.026, 7215009.694) ( 18d18' 7.30"E, 65d 1'20.47"N)
Lower Left  (  655527.026, 7185111.694) ( 18d16' 9.34"E, 64d45'16.27"N)
Upper Right (  692769.026, 7215009.694) ( 19d 5'25.83"E, 65d 0'10.17"N)
Lower Right (  692769.026, 7185111.694) ( 19d 2'59.88"E, 64d44' 6.82"N)
Center      (  674148.026, 7200060.694) ( 18d40'40.79"E, 64d52'45.30"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Min=0.000 Max=254.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=254.000, Mean=190.489, StdDev=67.650
  NoData Value=255
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=4576.531054018162,4394.433516189766,228.431113177739
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=254
    STATISTICS_MEAN=190.48910084315
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN=216,000000
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=67.650063222573
Band 2 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Min=0.000 Max=254.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=254.000, Mean=182.584, StdDev=65.131
  NoData Value=255
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=4394.433516189766,4241.999852082562,254.7048456178414
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=254
    STATISTICS_MEAN=182.58351941323
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN=206,000000
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=65.130636816191
Band 3 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Min=30.000 Max=253.000
  Minimum=30.000, Maximum=253.000, Mean=188.612, StdDev=15.632
  NoData Value=255
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=228.431113177739,254.7048456178414,244.3480753386218
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=253
    STATISTICS_MEAN=188.61166250665
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN=192,000000
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=30
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=15.631637001243


Build the vrt and then reproject

Reproject the vrt?

Do the stripes disappear if you zoom closer?

No, they don't disapear on zoom

Added some additional information in my question

Solved it. At least a workaround.
There seemd like it was some form of problem with the images with black stripes. The no data value in these images where 256 in the original files.
I ended up just opening the images in Paint.net and replaced the black border with a white one. Then I skipped the vrt and just added all the files directly to QGis, then they showed up as expected with no borders
